# Spark hangs during RDD reading

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have `Apache Spark` master node. When I try to iterate throught RDDs Spark hangs.

Here is an example of my code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Demo")
      .setMaster("spark://localhost:7077")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val records = sc.textFile("file:///Users/barbara/projects/spark/src/main/resources/videos.csv")    
println("Start")   

records.collect().foreach(println)    

println("Finish")
```

Spark log says:

```
Start
16/04/05 17:32:23 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/04/05 17:32:23 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at Application.scala:23
16/04/05 17:32:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at Application.scala:23) with 2 output partitions
16/04/05 17:32:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (collect at Application.scala:23)
16/04/05 17:32:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
16/04/05 17:32:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
16/04/05 17:32:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (file:///Users/barbara/projects/spark/src/main/resources/videos.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at Application.scala:19), which has no missing parents
16/04/05 17:32:23 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.0 KB, free 120.5 KB)
16/04/05 17:32:23 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1811.0 B, free 122.3 KB)
16/04/05 17:32:23 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 172.18.199.187:55983 (size: 1811.0 B, free: 2.4 GB)
16/04/05 17:32:23 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
16/04/05 17:32:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (file:///Users/barbara/projects/spark/src/main/resources/videos.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at Application.scala:19)
16/04/05 17:32:23 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks
```

I see only a "Start" message. Seems Spark do nothing to read RDDs. Any ideas how to fix it?

*UPD*

The data I want to read:

```
123v4n312bv4nb12,Action,Comedy
2n4vhj2gvrh24gvr,Action,Drama
sjfu326gjrw6g374,Drama,Horror
```

Comment: If I use `records.foreach(println)` Spark hangs anyway. I don't think that data is huge (see my update).

Comment: It is small, just a few lines.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto, for a 3 line file? It's already set to 1Gb

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto, i'm not the OP :) But running it locally is a good idea.

Comment: My `spark.executor.memory` is `2g`.

Comment: @barbara, no, it's not according to your example: `.set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")` so if that's not the code you're running, can you please edit your question to the exact code that shows the problem? Also, please do try running it locally

Comment: Hmm... I use `spark://localhost:7077` host. Is it a local host for Spark? Here is a command I use to start a cluster `sbin/start-master.sh`.

Comment: Dont you start a worker ?

Comment: @barbara did you solve your problem? Can you provide more information on this? I think I meet the same problem as you now. Spark just hangs on any RDD read methods. (read / count / first ...)

Answer (score 2):

If Spark hands on such a small dataset I would first look for:

- Am I trying to connect to a cluster that doesn't respond/exists? If I am trying to connect to a running cluster, I would first try to run the same code locally  `setMaster("local[*]")`. If this works, I would know that there is something going on with the "master" I try to connect to.
- Am I asking for more resources that what the cluster has to offer? For example, if the cluster manages 2G and I ask for a 3GB executor, my application will never get schedule and it will be in the job queue forever.

---

Specific to the comments above. If you started your cluster by `sbin/start-master.sh` you will NOT get a running cluster. At the very minimum you need a **master and a worker** (for standalone). You should use the `start-all.sh` script. I recommend a bit more homework and follow a tutorial.

Comment: This tells me that it hands on connecting with the "remote" cluster. Note that "local" runs everything on a single JVM, so there is not "connecting" going on. If you specify a different master, you need to make sure that the server is fully operational. Can you attach a screenshot of your Spark UI?

Comment: Hmm... now it works fine. I added to `SparkConf` a path to my fat jar: `setJars(Seq("Users/barbara/projects/spark/target/scala-2.10/learning-spark-assembly-0.0.1.jar"))`

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("/path/filename.csv")

    for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines) {
        println(line)
    }
```